# ExpressJS GET redirection

Tags: node.js, express

I'm implementing a little aunthentication routes on my Node app, as simple as this:

```
 app.get('/admin', function(req, res) {
    res.render('login', { error: false });
  });
  app.post('/admin', function(req, res) {    
    if((adminAccount.username === req.body.username) && 
      (adminAccount.password === req.body.password)) {

      res.redirect('/admin/books');
    }
    else {
      res.redirect('/admin', { error: true });
    }
  });
```

If I login with the right credentials it works flawless, how ever if I failed, it should make a GET request to `/admin` by redirect. 
However I get: `undefined. Redirecting to //127.0.0.1:3000/admin`

That makes me thing that `res.redirect` is making a `POST` request to `/admin` intead of a `GET` one.

What can I do? How do I specify `res.redirect` to redirect the right way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks ok to me, Can you try doing just this to rule out the error: false being the problem:

```
res.redirect('/admin');
```

If you want to flash a message, I would use connect-flash:

app.js:

```
var flash = require('connect-flash');
app.use(flash());
```

route:

```
req.flash('error', 'Woops, looks like that username and password are incorrect.');
res.redirect('/login');
```

middleware:

```
res.locals.message = req.flash();
```

view:

```
  <% if ( message.error ) { %>
    <div class="message error"><%= message.error %></div>
  <% } %>
```

Answer (score 0):

My experience. If you always get

> undefined. Redirecting to

replace

```
res.redirect('/admin', { error: true });
```

to

```
res.redirect('/admin');
```

If no error, keep trying what you want to do.